# iOS spellchecker making words plural

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm developing an application that has a UISearchBar.  After hitting the search button, the iOS spellchecker is offering to add an 's' to the search term.  For example, if I search for television, the spellchecker offers to change it to televisions.  Even if I search for foot, it offers to change it to foots.  That's not even correct.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see if there is something in way of help we can offer.

Comment: Just disable spell checker using spellCheckingType property.

Comment: Amp, I'm not even sure what code to post.  This problem happens even if I comment out the - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar; delegate method.
Max, that's my work around, but it's kind of nice having the spell checker.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UITextSpellCheckingType` to `UITextSpellCheckingTypeDefault`

Comment: I tried this in the init method of the views controller class and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you need the spell checking? You can disable the spell checking completely setting the property to  UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone

Comment: That's what I've currently done is disable the spell checker.  However that's more of a workaround than a solution.